# Strong Name Signing Azure Pipelines

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines, strongname, dotnet-cli

How do I sign my assembly with a strong name in Azure Pipelines?

Currently, I sign with a PFX file within Visual Studio. You can see the PFX [here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Device.Net/Device.Net.pfx). When I try to build in the current pipeline, the directive to sign the assembly is completely ignored. [This](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/4bd42c478b9af2d0dfd3f460a91e4b79f2ecb237/azure-pipelines.yml#L14) does not compile with a strong name.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the pfx file as a secure file in your Azure pipelines library and use the download secure file task to download the pfx file to your workspace.

Then import the signing key into the crypto storage of the user running the build. This blog post explains how to import the pfx using powershell.

https://www.karpach.com/visual-studio-team-services-assembly-signing.htm

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string] $PfxFilePath,
    [string] $PfxPassword
)

# The path to the snk file we're creating
[string] $snkFilePath = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PfxFilePath) + ".snk";

# Read in the bytes of the pfx file
[byte[]] $pfxBytes = Get-Content $PfxFilePath -Encoding Byte;

# Get a cert object from the pfx bytes with the private key marked as exportable
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
    $pfxBytes,
    $PfxPassword,
    [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable);

# Export a CSP blob from the cert (which is the same format as an SNK file)
[byte[]] $snkBytes = ([Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]$cert.PrivateKey).ExportCspBlob($true);

# Write the CSP blob/SNK bytes to the snk file
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes([IO.Path]::Combine([IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($PfxFilePath), $snkFilePath), $snkBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer here. This complicated. I was hoping that pipelines would have a task for this. But, if not, this will probably be the answer.

Comment: Hi @Christian Findlay,
I searched the [Extensions for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops) on Marketplace, and did not find any available extensions or tasks for strong-named signing assembly.
The answer shared by **jessehouwing** is a goos solution, you can mark it as the solution of this ticket. This may help more people who have the similar questions when they are looking for a solution.